# Missing Required Parameter in Docker File

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm learning how to use Jenkins and jenkinsfile for my CI/CD project, and when trying to run a docker image to run my selenium tests against, an error is thrown saying that the docker image param is missing.

I've followed the docks on the jenkins site for a tutorial and I'm now trying to fit that for my own purposes.

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            echo 'Building..'
            sh 'npm install'
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            echo 'Testing..'
             docker {
                        image 'selenium/standalone-firefox:3.141.59-gold' 
                        args '-p 4444:4444' 
                }
            sh 'npm test'
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            echo 'Deploying....'
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Docker should run on my Ubuntu server with port 4444 of the docker exposed and mapped to port 4444 of the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `Declarative Pipeline` for your Jenkinsfile, not `Scripted Pipeline`. For `Declarative Pipeline`, the `docker` is a directive which can only be used to specify `agent` for entire pipeline or stage as following:

```
pipeline {
   agent { // specify docker container for entire pipeline
      docker {
         image ''
         args ''
      }
   }
}

stage('test') {
   agent { // all steps of this stage will be executed inside this docker container
      docker {
         image ''
         args ''
      }
   }
}
```

You can't use this `docker` directive as pipeline step, like `sh`, 'echo'.

Jenkins indeed supply a `docker` DSL which can be directly used in `Scripted Pipeline`.

`Declarative Pipeline` supply a step `script` in where we can put **Scripted Pipeline-liked** script as following:

```
stage('test') {
  steps {
    script {
      def version = ....
      def img = docker.build(...)
      img.push()

      docker.image(...).inside(){}
    }
  }
}
```

Thus you can change your Jenkinsfile as following and give a trying.

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            echo 'Building..'
            sh 'npm install'
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            echo 'Testing..'
            script {
                docker.image('selenium/standalone-firefox:3.141.59-gold')
                      .inside('-p 4444:4444'){}
            }
            sh 'npm test'
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            echo 'Deploying....'
        }
    }
 }
}
```

By default the Docker Pipeline integrates assumes the default Docker Registry of [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/).

If you intend to use use a custom Docker Registry, you can use `docker.withRegistry` to specify the custom Registry URL and Credentials as following:

```
stage('Test') {
    steps {
        echo 'Testing..'

            script {
                docker.withRegistry('<custom docker registry>', 
                                    '<credentialsId for custom docker registry if required>') {
                    docker.image('selenium/standalone-firefox:3.141.59-gold')
                          .inside('-p 4444:4444'){}
                }
            }
        sh 'npm test'
    }
}
```

**Note:** If the custom docker registry need credentails, you have to add your account for custom docker registry into Jenkins via Jenkins Credentials. After adding, Jenkins will assign a id for your account, the id called credentialsId which used in above code.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that when I get home. Do I have to do this even though the docker image I am pulling down is already a public docker?

Comment: For the credentials, I'm assuming they are seperated? And not in the same string?

Comment: Thank you for that update and expanded explanation. This does seem to solve my issue, I think. And now on to the next!